# Problems specifying Laravel Eloquent database at runtime

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.8. I am trying to save an Eloquent model, choosing the database connection at runtime:

```
$catModel = new Cat;
if (env('USE_STAGING')) {
    $catModel->setConnection('staging');
}
$cat = $catModel::create(['name' => $request->name]);
```

My `config/database.php` file:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
    'staging' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('STAGING_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('STAGING_DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('STAGING_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('STAGING_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('STAGING_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('STAGING_DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```

My problem is that each time I run this code, the `cat` is created in the `mysql` (default) database, rather than the `staging` database, even when `USE_STAGING` is `true`.

Comment: You should never call `env()` outside of configuration files, it will return `null` if you cache your config, are you certain you are actually entering the if statement?

Comment: @Remul Ah good to know. But yes in this case I am entering the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the static call of the `create()` method.

By changing `$catModel::create()` to `$catModel->create()` it should use the correct connection:

```
$catModel = new Cat;

if (env('USE_STAGING')) {
    $catModel->setConnection('staging');
}

$cat = $catModel->create(['name' => $request->name]);
```